# What is the proper way to get contents of a page?

Tags: pages, content, the-content

The goal is very simple - to print page content on a page.
I tried:

```
<?php the_content() ?>
<?= get_the_content() ?>
```

then

```
<?php the_content(get_the_ID()) ?>
<?= get_the_content(get_the_ID()) ?>
```

None of them worked.

Then I found this bizarre solution:

```
<?= apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', get_the_ID() )) ?>
```

Why the_content() and get_the_content() didn't work?

Is there cleaner solution to display page content then the last one?

Comment: Please post the entire code of the `page.php`. Or, have a look at a nicer solution like [`_s`](https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/page.php) with the [actual part](https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/template-parts/content-page.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few notes before I start

- NEVER EVER use php shortcodes, they are bad, confusing and not supported by default on some servers. IMHO, they should have never made it into PHP in the first place. WordPress Standards (*which doesn't mean much*) also "prohibits" the use of shorttags. Use proper php tags and forget that shorttags even exists
- [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) and [`get_the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) does not accept the post ID, the firts parameter for both these template tags are `$more_link_text`
- `get_the_content()` as well as the the content retrieved from the post_content field are unfiltered content, `the_content` filters are a set of filters that are applied to this unfiltered content and they include filters like `wpautop` which apply `p` tags to `the_content()`

Popular believe is that `the_content()` and `get_the_content()` **MUST** be used inside the loop. That is not entirely true, although it really is not recommended to use it outside the loop. Just like [`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/), `get_the_content()` expects global post data to be set up (*`$post = get_post()`*), so if there are postdata available outside the loop in global scope, it will return the data.

Your issue is quite strange, if we look at source codes here, both `get_the_ID()` and `get_the_content()` calls `$post = get_post()`, and [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) returns `$GLOBALS['post']` if no ID is passed and if `$GLOBALS['post']` are set, which seems to be the case here. `get_post_field()` successfully returns the page content according to you which means `get_the_ID()` returns the correct page ID that we are one, which means that `get_the_content()` should have worked and should have returned unfiltered page content (*`the_content()` should have displayed filtered page content*)

Anyways, you will need to debug this why things does not want to work as expected. To answer your question as to displaying page content without the loop correctly and reliably, you can access the queried object, get the `$post_content` property, apply the content filters to it and display the content. Just one note, this will not work if you are using `query_posts` in any way as it breaks the main query object which hold the queried object. This is the main reason why do must never ever use `query_posts`

```
$current_page = get_queried_object();
$content      = apply_filters( 'the_content', $current_page->post_content );
echo $content;
```

Comment: Wow, that's what I call an answer! 1) I know it's bad to use <? ... ?> kind of tags, but have also heard using <?= ... ?> are okay, and they don't require shortags enabled. 2) Yeah putting ids there was stupid of me...)) 3) I just tried the_content() returns nothing without the Loop. 4) I must add that I use page-about.php template and then use get_template_part('templates/content', 'about') function to get about page content.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ;-). The old style `<?php` tags are still the prefered and recommended tag to use.  Just a note on your 4th point, yes, that will be best, but requires the loop, which is what you wanted to avoid in the first place. ;-).

Comment: I guess I made peace with using the Loop. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Displays the contents of the current post. This template tag must be within while loop.

```
<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            the_content(); 
        } // end while
    } // end if
?>
```

More : [the_content() - WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content)

Comment: I just want to display the content of the current page. I don't want to use The Loop for this.

Comment: You must use the loop .

Comment: Ok, next question. Why does apply_filters() function worked without the loop?

Comment: Because apply_filters() is a WordPress built-in function and it rewrite new filters on default WordPress filters .